# How to set a string for Toast.makeToast(...) in android

Tags: android, toast

In my class MainActivity I created a string:

```
String s = "Mystring";
```

And I want to do something like below:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Is it possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: what happens when you try? Give it a try

Comment: This should work i guess.

Comment: You just did? Not sure where you're after..

Comment: see my comment below the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int%29) of `Toast.makeText()`:

```
/**
 * Make a standard toast that just contains a text view.
 *
 * @param context The context to use. Usually your Application or Activity object.
 * @param text The text to show. Can be formatted text.
 * @param duration How long to display the message. Either LENGTH_SHORT or LENGTH_LONG.
 */
public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration){ ... }
```

Notice the use of `makeTEXT`, not `makeTOAST`.

---

You mentioned you're working in an `AsyncTask`. It is not possible to create toasts from a non-UI thread. Make sure you're displaying your Toast either in `onPreExecute`, in `onPostExecute`, or in `onProgressUpdate`.

Comment: check this library `compile 'com.shamanland:xdroid-toaster:0.0.5'`, it doesn't require `runOnUiThread()` or `Context` variable, all routine is gone! just invoke `Toaster.toast(R.string.my_msg);` here is the example: https://github.com/shamanland/xdroid-toaster-example

Answer (score 0):

Ya that should work, wht is the problem you getting actually?

Try below code:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I am working in inner class extending AsyncTask<...> And I do so it crashes

Comment: @BlediBoss your app being crash because you have tried to update UI in background

Comment: @BlediBoss and why didn't you mention this circumstance?

Comment: Just write above line in onPostExecute() method not in doInBackground method.

Comment: Wait...! write `Toast.makeText()` not `Toast.makeToast()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using it inside an `AsyncTask` then write your code in `onPostexecute()` as you can't access it from `doInBackground()` since it's Non-UI thread.

`Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Comment: @BlediBoss Did you write it inside `onPostExecute()`? Also you are using `Toast.makeToast()` which is incorrect use `Toast.makeText()`

Comment: @AndroidWarrior `Toast.makeToast` have a compile error, he/she can't run app at all

Comment: yeah that is a typo I will fix it. I executed it in background, that's why it did not work :)

Comment: @shayanpourvatan Agreed mate but just since it was there i pointed it out.

Answer (score -1):

```
String s="haha";
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = s;
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration).show();
```

//you are correct. just use charSequence equal to the string. it should work. works for me.